# how to merge two sorted array in one sorted array in JavaScript without using sort()

Tags: javascript

In this program merged two array and then sorted using temp.but this not correct method.because two array are sorted ,so method should be unique i.e. merging of two sorted in sorted form should be unique.

Example:

- `a=[1,2,3,5,9]`
- `b=[4,6,7,8]`

```js
function mergeSortdArray(a,b){
 for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
  a.push(b[i]);
 }
 //console.log(a);
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
```

Comment: how to merge two sorted array in one sorted array in  JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

Based on Eric Lundgren's answer above, but this fixes a couple of major bugs and is more efficient. Worked for me in production. I included using a sort function for more complex solutions - for this simple case you can just test for a > b as in Eric's answer if you want.

```
function mergeSortedArray(a, b) {
    var sorted = [], indexA = 0, indexB = 0;

    while (indexA < a.length && indexB < b.length) {
        if (sortFn(a[indexA], b[indexB]) > 0) {
            sorted.push(b[indexB++]);
        } else {
            sorted.push(a[indexA++]);
        }
    }

    if (indexB < b.length) {
        sorted = sorted.concat(b.slice(indexB));
    } else {
        sorted = sorted.concat(a.slice(indexA));
    }

    return sorted;
}

function sortFn(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

console.log(mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
```

Comment: Why did you use a sortFn instead of simply comparing 2 values?

Comment: Sometimes sorting is more complicated than just comparing two values - I mentioned in the answer that if yours is simple you can just use it directly if you want. IIRC my case was more complicated and I simplified the code for the post.

Answer (score 8):

How about something like this?

Since a and b are both sorted we only need to consider the top or first item of each array when adding. Note that this method will modify both a and b during execution, this may not be what you want, in which case you can add this code at the start:

```
var tempA = a.slice();
var tembB = b.slice();
```

This will make copies of the array which you can then use instead of `a` and `b` in the function below:

```js
function mergeSortedArray(a,b){
    var tempArray = [];
    while(a.length || b.length) {
        if(typeof a[0] === 'undefined') {
            tempArray.push(b[0]);
            b.splice(0,1);
        } else if(a[0] > b[0]){
            tempArray.push(b[0]);
            b.splice(0,1);
        } else {
            tempArray.push(a[0]);
            a.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
console.log(mergeSortedArray([4,6,7,8], [1,2,3,5,9]));
```

Without using splice at all, try something like this:

```js
function mergeSortedArray(a,b){
    var tempArray = [];
    var currentPos = {
        a: 0,
        b: 0
    }
    while(currentPos.a < a.length || currentPos.b < b.length) {
        if(typeof a[currentPos.a] === 'undefined') {
            tempArray.push(b[currentPos.b++]);
        } else if(a[currentPos.a] > b[currentPos.b]){
            tempArray.push(b[currentPos.b++]);
        } else {
            tempArray.push(a[currentPos.a++]);
        }
    }
    return tempArray;
}
console.log(mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
```

Comment: what will be without using splice.

Comment: If you don't want to splice the arrays you can use the tempA and tempB variables above my example.

Comment: @AmitModi see my edit now. I tihink the method that doesn't splice at all is needlessly more complicated than just replacing a and b with tempA and tempB

Comment: This does not handle the case of an empty array

Comment: @thegalah On chrome I've tried running the snippets in all empty combinations (a empty, b empty and both empty) and they produce the correct results as far as I can tell. Why does it not handle the case of an empty array?

Answer (score 7):

Hey I ran everyone's code from above against a simple .concat() and .sort() method. With both large and small arrays, the .concat() and .sort() completes in less time, significantly.

```
console.time("mergeArrays");
mergeArrays([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8])
console.timeEnd("mergeArrays");
//mergeArrays: 0.299ms

console.time("concat sort");
[1,2,3,5,9].concat([4,6,7,8]).sort();
console.timeEnd("concat sort");
//concat sort:0.018ms
```

With arrays of 10,000 size, the difference is even larger with the concat and sort running even faster than before (4.831 ms vs .008 ms).

What's happening in javascript's sort that makes it faster?

Comment: Clearly mentioned in question, to answer not using `sort` method

Answer (score 2):

**Merge two sorted arrays in JavaScript**

```
var SortedArrays = function(nums1, nums2) {
    let array = [];
    let leftIndex = 0, rightIndex = 0;
    while(leftIndex < nums1.length && rightIndex < nums2.length) {
        if(nums1[leftIndex] < nums2[rightIndex]) {
            array.push(nums1[leftIndex]);
            leftIndex++;
        } else {
            array.push(nums2[rightIndex]);
            rightIndex++;
        }
    }
    array = array.concat(nums1.slice(leftIndex)).concat(nums2.slice(rightIndex));
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**can do with es6 spread operator**

```js
let a=[1,2,3,5,9]
let b=[4,6,7,8]

let newArray=[...a,...b].sort()
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: Not worked if you add double digit number to the array. try this inputs - [1,2,3,5,9],[4,16,7,8]

Answer (score 1):

I needed it so implemented my ownn

```
mergesortedarray(a, b) {
  let c = new Array(a.length+b.length);
  for(let i=0, j=0, k=0; i<c.length; i++)
    c[i] = j < a.length && (k == b.length || a[j] < b[k]) ? a[j++] : b[k++];
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. I'm using [1,2,4,8],[8,10,7,3]

Answer (score 1):

**Shortest** Merge Sorted arrays without sort() plus, without using third temp array.

```
function mergeSortedArray (a, b){
  let index = 0;

  while(b.length > 0 && a[index]) {
    if(a[index] > b[0]) {
      a.splice(index, 0, b.shift());
    }
    index++;
  }
  return [...a, ...b];
}
mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8])
```

Comment: This would not work if one array contains some negative numbers. If you call the function with those arguments: `mergeSortedArray([0,0,0], [-1,0,1])` and the result would be `[0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1]`. Also, probably splicing might not the fastest method that could be implemented for such an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**now you can do with es6 (...)spread operator**

```
========================================
   using es6 (...)spread operator
========================================
let a=[1,2,3,5,9]
let b=[4,6,7,8]

let sortedArray=[...a,...b].sort()
console.log(sortedArray) 

outputy :- [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

========================================
       2nd way 
========================================


function mergeSortedArray(a, b) {
    var sortedArray = [], indexA = 0, indexB = 0;

    while (indexA < a.length && indexB < b.length) {
        if (sortFuntion(a[indexA], b[indexB]) > 0) {
            sortedArray.push(b[indexB++]);
        } else {
            sortedArray.push(a[indexA++]);
        }
    }

    if (indexB < b.length) {
        sortedArray = sortedArray.concat(b.slice(indexB));
    } else {
        sortedArray = sortedArray.concat(a.slice(indexA));
    }

    return sortedArray;
}

function sortFuntion(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

console.log(mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
output :- 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add a solution that included an array with an initialized size, so that there are no copies of the arrays made outside of the new sorted array.  This means no calls to `slice` or extra `concat`:

```js
function defaultComparator(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function mergeSortedArray(arrA, arrB, comparator) {
    var _comparator = (typeof comparator === 'undefined')
        ? defaultComparator
        : comparator;
    var idxA = 0, idxB = 0, idxS = 0;
    var arrSorted = new Array(arrA.length + arrB.length);
    while (idxA < arrA.length || idxB < arrB.length) {
        if (idxA >= arrA.length)
            arrSorted[idxS++] = arrB[idxB++];
        else if (idxB >= arrB.length)
            arrSorted[idxS++] = arrA[idxA++];
        else if (_comparator(arrA[idxA], arrB[idxB]) <= 0)
            arrSorted[idxS++] = arrA[idxA++];
        else
            arrSorted[idxS++] = arrB[idxB++];
    }
    return arrSorted;
}

console.log(mergeSortedArray([0,2,3,5,9],[-3,1,5,6,9.5]));
console.log(mergeSortedArray(
    [{ n: 0 }, { n: 2 }, { n: 3 }, { n: 5 }, { n: 9 }],
    [{ n: -2 }, { n: 0 }, { n: 4 }],
    function(a, b) { return a.n - b.n; }
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets implement a generic merger. Assuming that we don't know whether they are sorted ascending or descending we first need to apply a test to derive a compare function `cf`. Then it's a simple recursive walk as follows;

```js
function merger(a, b){
  var cf = a[0] < a[1] || b[0] < b[1] ? (x,y) => x < y
                                      : a[0] > a[1] || b[0] > b[1] ? (x,y) => x > y
                                                                   : (x,y) => false,
      mg = ([a,...as],[b,...bs]) => a !== void 0 &&
                                    b !== void 0  ? cf(a,b) ? [a].concat(mg(as,[b,...bs]))
                                                            : [b].concat(mg([a,...as],bs))
                                                  : a === void 0 ? [b,...bs]
                                                                 : [a,...as];
  return mg(a,b);
}

var a = [1,2,3,5,9,10,11,12],
    b = [4,6,7,8,17],
    c = [9,8,7],
    d = [23,11,10,4,3,2,1];

console.log(merger(a,b));
console.log(merger(c,d));
```

Note: The tester to decide whether ascending or descending is sloppy. It doesn't even check equity of first two. It's just to give an idea. Implementing it properly is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

## Merge Two Sorted Arrays

```
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
    const arr = [];

    while (arr1.length && arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[0] < arr2[0]) {
            arr.push(arr1.shift());
        } else {
            arr.push(arr2.shift());
        }
    }
    return [...arr, ...arr1, ...arr2];
}
```

** If you want to merge the arrays in-place, clone each array and use it in the while loop instead.*

*Example:* `clonedArr1 = [...arr1];`

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeArrays(arr1, arr2) {

    if (!arePopulatedArrays(arr1, arr2))
        return getInvalidArraysResult(arr1, arr2);

    let arr1Index = 0;
    let arr2Index = 0;
    const totalItems = arr1.length + arr2.length;
    const mergedArray = new Array(totalItems);

    for (let i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {

        if (hasItems(arr1, arr1Index)) {

            if (hasItems(arr2, arr2Index)) {

                if (HasSmallestItem(arr1, arr2, arr1Index, arr2Index)) {
                    mergedArray[i] = arr1[arr1Index++];
                } else {
                    mergedArray[i] = arr2[arr2Index++];
                }
            } else {
                mergedArray[i] = arr1[arr1Index++];
            }
        } else {
            mergedArray[i] = arr2[arr2Index++];
        }
    }
    return mergedArray;
}

function arePopulatedArrays(arr1, arr2) {

    if (!arr1 || arr1.length === 0)
        return false;

    if (!arr2 || arr2.length === 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}

function getInvalidArraysResult(arr1, arr2) {

    if (!arr1 && !arr2)
        return [];

    if ((!arr2 || arr2.length === 0) && (arr1 && arr1.length !== 0))
        return arr1;

    if ((!arr1 || arr1.length === 0) && (arr2 && arr2.length !== 0))
        return arr2;

    return [];
}

function hasItems(arr, index) {
    return index < arr.length;
}

function HasSmallestItem(arr1, arr2, arr1Index, arr2Index) {
    return arr1[arr1Index] <= arr2[arr2Index];
}
```

Comment: Im not using Array.push() or Array.shift() for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about performance of the sort operation, you can use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```
var a=[1,2,3,5,9];
var b=[4,6,7,8];
var c = a.concat(b).sort((a,b)=>a > b);
console.log(c)
```

Of course, using the knowledge that the two arrays are already sorted can reduce runtime.

Answer (score 0):

**Merge two arrays and create new array.**

```js
function merge_two_sorted_arrays(arr1, arr2) {
        let i = 0;
        let j = 0;
        let result = [];
        while(i < arr1.length && j < arr2.length) {
            if(arr1[i] <= arr2[j]) {
                result.push(arr1[i]);
                i++;
            } else {
                result.push(arr2[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i < arr1.length ) {
            result.push(arr1[i]);
            i++;
        }
        while(j < arr2.length ) {
            result.push(arr2[j]);
            j++;
        }
        console.log(result);
    }

merge_two_sorted_arrays([15, 24, 36, 37, 88], [3, 4, 10, 11, 13, 20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Merge two sorted arrays - Answer with comments

```
const mergeArrays = (arr1, arr2) => { // function to merge two sorted arrays
  if (!arr1 || !arr2) { // if only one array is passed
    return "Invalid Array" // message is returned
  }
  if (arr1.length < 1) { // if first array is empty
    if (arr2.length < 1) { // if second array is empty
      return "Both arrays are empty" // returns message
    }
    return arr2; // else returns second array
  }
  if (arr2.length < 1) { // if second array is empty
    if (arr1.length < 1) { // if both arrays are empty
      return "Both arrays are empty" // returns message
    }
    return arr1; // else returns first array
  }
  let small = []; // initializes empty array to store the smaller array
  let large = []; // initializes empty array to store the larger array
  arr1.length < arr2.length ? [small, large] = [arr1, arr2] : [small, large] = [arr2, arr1]; // stores smaller array in small and larger array in large
  const len1 = small.length; // stores length of small in len1
  const len2 = large.length; // stores length of large in len2
  let ansArr = []; // initializes an empty array to create the merged array
  let i = 0; // initializes i to 0 to iterate through small
  let j = 0; // initializes j to 0 to iterate through large
  while (small[i]!==undefined && large[j]!==undefined) { //while element in arrays at i and j position respectively exists
    if(small[i] < large[j]) { // if element from small is smaller than element in large
      ansArr.push(small[i]); // add that element to answer
      i++; // move to the next element
    } else { // if element from large is smaller than element in small
      ansArr.push(large[j]); // add that element to answer
      j++; // move to the next element
    }
  }
  if (i < len1) { // if i has not reached the end of array
    ansArr = [...ansArr, ...small.splice(i)]; // add the rest of the elements at the end of the answer
  } else { // if j has not reached the end of array
    ansArr = [...ansArr, ...large.splice(j)]; // add the rest of the elements at the end of the answer
  }
  return ansArr; // return answer
}

console.log(mergeArrays([0,1,5], [2,3,4,6,7,8,9])); // example
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging two sorted arrays.

```js
function merge(a, b) {
  let i = a.length - 1;
  let j = b.length - 1;
  let k = i + j + 1; //(a.length + b.length - 1) == (i + j + 2 - 1) == (i + j + 1)

  while (k >= 0) {
    if (a[i] > b[j] || j < 0) {
      a[k] = a[i];
      i--;
    } else {
      a[k] = b[j];
      j--;
    }
    k--;
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(merge([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]));
```

More compact code:

```js
function merge(a, b) {
  let i = a.length - 1;
  let j = b.length - 1;
  let k = i + j + 1; //(a.length + b.length - 1) == (i + j + 2 - 1) == (i + j + 1)

  while (k >= 0) {
    a[k--] = (a[i] > b[j] || j < 0) ? a[i--] : b[j--];
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(merge([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see with most solutions here is that they don't precreate the array, just pushing into an array when you know the end game size is a little bit wasteful.

This is my suggestion, we can make it a little more efficient but it will make it less readable:

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(arr1, arr2) {
  let i1 = 0, i2 = 0;
  return [...arr1, ...arr2].map(
   () =>
    i1 === arr1.length ? arr2[i2++] :
    i2 === arr2.length ? arr1[i1++] :
    arr1[i1] < arr2[i2]? arr1[i1++] :
    arr2[i2++]
  );
}

console.log(mergeSortedArrays([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find here also an implementation for merging two sorted Arrays. Actually, we could compare one by one the Array items pushing them to a new Array and when we parse completely one Array, we just concat the sliced part of the second already sorted Array.

```
const merge = (arr1, arr2) => {
    let arr = [];
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    while (i < arr1.length || j < arr2.length) {
        if (i === arr1.length) {
            return arr.concat(arr2.slice(j));
        }
        if (j === arr2.length) {
            return arr.concat(arr1.slice(i));
        }
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            arr.push(arr1[i]);
            i++
        } else {
            arr.push(arr2[j]);
            j++
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Fastest Merge of 2 Sorting array**

```js
function merge(a, b) {
  let i = 0,
    j = 0;
  let array = [];
  let counter = 0;
  while (i < a.length && j < b.length) {
    if (a[i] > b[j]) array[counter++] = b[j++];
    else if (a[i] < b[j]) array[counter++] = a[i++];
    else (array[counter++] = a[i++]), j++;
  }
  while (j < b.length) {
    array[counter++] = b[j++];
  }
  while (i < a.length) {
    array[counter++] = a[i++];
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(merge([1, 3], [2, 4, 5]));

console.log(merge([1, 3, 123, 125, 127], [2, 41, 50]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let Array1 = [10,20,30,40];
let Array2 = [15,25,35];
let mergeArray=(arr1, arr2)=>{
    for(var i = arr2.length-1; i>= 0; i--){
        let curr1 = arr2[i]
        for(var j = arr1.length-1; j>= 0; j--){
            let curr2 = arr1[j]
            if(curr1<curr2){
                arr1[j+1]  = curr2
            }else{
                arr1[j+1]  = curr1
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr1
}

mergeArray(Array1, Array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeSortedArray(a, b){
var merged = [], 
aElm = a[0],
  bElm = b[0],
  i = 1,
  j = 1;
 if(a.length ==0)
   return b;
     if(b.length ==0)
       return a;
      while(aElm || bElm){
        if((aElm && !bElm) || aElm < bElm){
           merged.push(aElm);
              aElm = a[i++];
         }   
         else {
                merged.push(bElm);
                bElm = b[j++];
              }
      }
      return merged;
    }
    
   //check

 > mergeSortedArray([2,5,6,9], [1,2,3,29]);
 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 29]
```

hope this helps, please correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on it for while now, and I have found a good solution. I didn't came up with this algorithm, but I implemented it properly in Javscript. I have tested it with massive number of array, and I have included comments so it's easier to understand. Unlike many other solutions, this one of the most efficient one, and I have included some tests. You run the code to verify that works. Time Complexity of a this solution is **O(n)**

```js
function mergeTwoSortedArraay(rightArr, leftArr) {
 // I decided to call frist array "rightArr" and second array "leftArr"
  var mergedAr = [], sizeOfMergedArray = rightArr.length + leftArr.length; // so if rightArray has 3 elements and leftArr has 4, mergedArray will have 7.
   var r = 0, l =0; // r is counter of rightArr and l is for leftArr;
   for(var i =0; i< sizeOfMergedArray; ++i) {
       if(rightArr[r] >= leftArr[l] || r >= rightArr.length) { // r >= rightArr.length when r is equal to greater than length of array, if that happens we just copy the reaming 
        // items of leftArr to mergedArr

            mergedAr[i] = leftArr[l];
            l++;
       } else { 
           mergedAr[i] = rightArr[r];
           r++;
       }
   }
   return mergedAr;
}
// few tests
console.log(mergeTwoSortedArraay([ 0, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 ],[ 0, 4, 5, 6, 9 ]));

console.log(mergeTwoSortedArraay([ 7, 13, 14, 51, 79 ],[ -356, 999 ]));
console.log(mergeTwoSortedArraay([ 7, 23, 64, 77 ],[ 18, 42, 45, 90 ]));
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the cleanest approach but give it a try.

```
function mergeSortedArrays(array1, array2){
  const mergedArray = [];
  let array1Item = array1[0];
  let array2Item = array2[0];
  let i = 1;
  let j = 1;
 
  if(array1.length === 0) {
    return array2;
  }
  if(array2.length === 0) {
    return array1;
  }

  while (array1Item || array2Item){
   if(array2Item === undefined || array1Item < array2Item){
     mergedArray.push(array1Item);
     array1Item = array1[i];
     i++;
   }   
   else {
     mergedArray.push(array2Item);
     array2Item = array2[j];
     j++;
   }
  }
  return mergedArray;
}

mergeSortedArrays([0,3,4,31], [3,4,6,30]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Everything fine but small mistake down there

function sortedArray(a,b){
    for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        a.push(b[i]);
    }
    //console.log(a);
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    //<!--You did a mistake here you have loop through for to get array elements-->
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    return a;
    }
}
console.log(sortedArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case using the built in sorted method is not allowed:

```
function mergeSortedArrays(a, b) {
   let storage = [];
   let aLen = a.length;
   let bLen = b.length;
   let i = 0;
   let j = 0;

   while(i < aLen || j < bLen){ 
     if(a[i] < b[j]){
       storage.push(a[i]);
       i++;
     }
     else if(a[i] >= b[j]){
       storage.push(b[j]);
       j++;
     }
     else if(a[i] === undefined){
       storage.push(b[j]);
       j++;
     }
     else if(b[j] === undefined){
       storage.push(a[i]);
       i++;
     }
   }
   return storage
}
```

If using sorted method is allowed, this is much better:

```
function mergeSortedArrays(a, b){
   let result = a.concat(b);  //concat both arrays into one first
   return result.sort((a,b) => a - b)  //then sort the concated array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(a, b) {
    //Setting up the needed variables
    let mergedArray = [], aIndex = 0, bIndex = 0, 
        mergedIndex = 0, aCount = a.length, 
        bCount = b.length;
        
    //Loop until all items from the array merges in
    while (mergedIndex < (aCount + bCount)) {
        mergedArray[mergedIndex++] = (a[aIndex] < b[bIndex]) ? a[aIndex++] : b[bIndex++];
    }
    return mergedArray;
}
    mergeSortedArrays([1, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 20, 30, 40]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple code to achieve this goal:

```
function mergeSortetArrays(array1, array2) {
const mergedArray = []; //This is const, we don't have to change the type of this array
let array1Item = array1[0];// We use let, because it will store undefined
let array2Item = array2[0];
let i = 1;
let j = 1;

//check input
if(array1.length === 0)
    return array2;
if(array2.length === 0)
    return array1;

//loop through each array, and store to the mergedArray
    while( array1Item || array2Item) {
       console.log(array1Item, array2Item);
        if (!array2Item || array1Item < array2Item) {
            mergedArray.push(array1Item);
            array1Item = array1[i]
            i++;
            } else {
                mergedArray.push(array2Item);
                array2Item = array2[j];
                j++;
         }
   }
   return mergedArray;
 }

console.log(mergeSortetArrays([0, 1, 3, 5,7,8, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Merge N sorted arrays

Based on Dovev Hefetz's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48147806/1167223) but supports `N` arrays and accepts `sortFn` as an attribute

```
function mergeArrays(arrays, sortFn) {
  return arrays.reduce(function mergeArray(arrayA, arrayB, index) {
    // For the first iteration return the first array
    if (index === 0) {
      return arrayA;
    }

    const sorted = [];
    let indexA = 0;
    let indexB = 0;

    while (indexA < arrayA.length && indexB < arrayB.length) {
      if (sortFn(arrayA[indexA], arrayB[indexB]) > 0) {
        sorted.push(arrayB[indexB++]);
      } else {
        sorted.push(arrayA[indexA++]);
      }
    }
  
    // Add any remaining entries
    if (indexB < arrayB.length) {
      return sorted.concat(arrayB.slice(indexB));
    } else {
      return sorted.concat(arrayA.slice(indexA));
    };
  }, arrays[0]);
}
```

### Example use

```js
const merged = mergeArrays([
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6],
  [0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
], (v1, v2) => v1 - v2);

console.log(merged);

/*
Results:
[
  0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2,
  2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4,
  4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6,
  6
]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to merge two sorted array in javascript.

```js
class MergeSortArray {
  arr1 = [];
  arr2 = [];
  arr3 = [];

  constructor(arr1, arr2) {
    this.arr1 = arr1;
    this.arr2 = arr2;
  }

  mergeArray() {
    let n1 = this.arr1.length;
    let n2 = this.arr2.length;
    let i = 0,
      j = 0,
      k = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
      if (this.arr1[i] < this.arr2[j]) {
        this.arr3[k++] = this.arr1[i++];
      } else {
        this.arr3[k++] = this.arr2[j++];
      }
    }

    // Store remaining elements of first array
    while (i < n1) this.arr3[k++] = this.arr1[i++];

    // Store remaining elements of second array
    while (j < n2) this.arr3[k++] = this.arr2[j++];

    return this.arr3;
  }
}
let obj = new MergeSortArray([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11], [2, 4, 6, 8]);
let arr3 = obj.mergeArray();
console.log(arr3);
```

> You can find the code in StackBlitz editor here : [Merge two sorted array](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mp1ajm)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for merging two sorted array with Time complexity and space complexity of **O(n)**

Most of the answers are correct but they have ignored equal value comparison

```js
function merge(arr1, arr2) {
  let index1 = 0
  let index2 = 0
  const mergedArray = []
  while (index1 < arr1.length || index2 < arr2.length) {
    if (arr1[index1] < arr2[index2] || index2 === arr2.length) {
      mergedArray.push(arr1[index1])
      index1++
    } else if (arr1[index1] > arr2[index2] || index1 === arr1.length) {
      mergedArray.push(arr2[index2])
      index2++
    } else if (arr1[index1] === arr2[index2]) {
      mergedArray.push(arr1[index1])
      mergedArray.push(arr2[index2])
      index1++
      index2++
    }
  }
  return mergedArray
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(merge([1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10], [2, 4, 6, 11, 12])))
```

Comment: there is a bug `merge([1, 1, 2], [2, 2]) = [1, 1, 2, undefined, 2]`

Comment: Thanks, @zakariamouhid for throwing light on this bug. I have updated the code for it

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mergeSortdArray(a,b){
    for(var i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        a.push(b[i]);
    }
    //console.log(a);
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]>a[j])
            {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return a;
}
console.log(mergeSortdArray([1,2,3,5,9],[4,6,7,8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("merge sorted array::", mergeBinaryArray([1,4,5,34,36],  [2,4,5,6,7,8]))
function mergeBinaryArray(array1, array2){
let p1 = 0, p2= 0, p3 =0, sortedArray = []; 
while( p1 < array1.length && p2 < array2.length){
    if(array1[p1] < array2[p2]){
        sortedArray[p3] = array1[p1]
        p1++;
        p3++
    }else{
        sortedArray[p3] = array2[p2]
        p2++;
        p3++;
    }

}
if(p1 < array1.length){
   for(let index = p1; index < array1.length; index++){
       sortedArray.push(array1[index]);
       p3++
   }

}
if(p2 < array2.length){
   for(let index= p2; index< array2.length; index++){
       sortedArray.push(array2[index]);
       p3++;
   }
   
}
return sortedArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below solution. Stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-mp1ajm?file=index.js

```js
class MergeSortArray {
  arr1 = [];
  arr2 = [];
  arr3 = [];

  constructor(arr1, arr2) {
    this.arr1 = arr1;
    this.arr2 = arr2;
  }

  mergeArray() {
    let n1 = this.arr1.length;
    let n2 = this.arr2.length;
    let i = 0,
      j = 0,
      k = 0;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
      if (this.arr1[i] < this.arr2[j]) {
        this.arr3[k++] = this.arr1[i++];
      } else {
        this.arr3[k++] = this.arr2[j++];
      }
    }

    // Store remaining elements of first array
    while (i < n1) this.arr3[k++] = this.arr1[i++];

    // Store remaining elements of second array
    while (j < n2) this.arr3[k++] = this.arr2[j++];

    return this.arr3;
  }
}
let obj = new MergeSortArray([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 67], [2, 4, 6, 8]);
let arr3 = obj.mergeArray();
console.log(arr3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 11]
var b = [4, 6, 7, 8]
var c = [];

function mergeArr() {
  for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if (!c.includes(b[i])) {
        c.push(b[i]);
      }
      if (!c.includes(a[j])) {
        c.push(a[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  organizeArr(c)
}

function organizeArr() {
  let organizer;
  for (let index = 0; index < c.length; index++) {
    for (let j = index + 1; j < c.length; j++) {
      if (c[index] > c[j]) {
        organizer = c[index]
        c[index] = c[j]
        c[j] = organizer
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(c);

}
mergeArr()
```

First Merge Array and then sort array which returns this function can be scalable up to n number

Answer (score -1):

```js
function mergeSortedArray(a, b) {
    var arr = a.concat(b).sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
     });
    return arr;
 }
 console.log(mergeSortedArray(a, b));
```