# merge two sorted array into new array in sorted order and remove element(number) from original array.(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, sorting

in merging process compare number of both array and  push in new array and remove from original array. use while loop for this process.my wrong program is:

```js
function mergeSortedArray(a, b){
  var temp=[];
  var i=0;
  var j=0;
  while(a[i]||b[j]){
    if(a[i]<b[j]){
      temp.push(a[i])
      i++;
    }
    else{
      temp.push(b[j]);
      j++;
    }

      }
      return temp;
}

  

console.log(mergeSortedArray([1,2,3,5,8],[1,2,4,6,9,10]));
```

Comment: i used pointer in this code.

Comment: Why don't you try debugging your code? Step through it line by line to see what it is doing. Also, look at your code closely and think about what it is doing, especially when it reaches the end of one array or the other.

Comment: Your wrong code is working good on my end. What is the problem ?

Comment: he hasn't even written the whole question yet

Comment: duplicated HIS OWN QUESTION - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922223/how-to-merge-two-sorted-array-in-one-sorted-array-in-javascript-without-using-so

Comment: here pointer is not like C language pointer

Comment: `var a = [3, 9, 34, 198, 200, 203, 222, 777];
var b =[5, 6, 8,9,12, 34,78]; 
var arr = []; 
var i = 0; 
var j = 0; 
var totalsize = a.length + b.length; 
var temp = 0; 
while(temp < totalsize) { 
 if ((a[i] < b[j])||(a[i]==b[j])){ 
  arr.push(a[i]); i++; 
 }else {
  arr.push(b[j]); j++; 
 } temp++; 
} 
console.log('final : '+arr);` [mergeSort](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/07/02/friday-algorithms-javascript-merge-sort/)

Comment: @AmitModi There is no pointer in javascript. What you probably mean is `iterators`, which is using pointers under the hood but you won't ever touch them directly.

Comment: modify my code for remove number from original array and add to the new array in sorted order.

Comment: @Frederik.L, in any language you can use a varible as a pointer. For example in javascript you can make a variable that *points* to the currently processed index of an array. It would be fair to call such a variable a pointer. In programming, the word pointer *also* has a narrow and specific meaning that you are referring to, but it's not the meaning that was used here.